# Cleaner way of iterating nested JSON in ruby

Tags: json, ruby, loops, nested

I was wondering if there is any 'cleaner' way of looping through nested JSON in ruby? 
This is my JSON object:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "file": "test/test_project_js/jquery.js",
      "results": [
        {
          "vulnerabilities": [
            {
              "severity": "high"
            },
            {
              "severity": "medium"
            },
            {
              "severity": "none"
            },
            {
              "severity": "high"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "test/test_project_js/jquery.js",
      "results": [
        {
          "vulnerabilities": [
            {
              "severity": "none"
            },
            {
              "severity": "none"
            },
            {
              "severity": "none"
            },
            {
              "severity": "high"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract `severity` under each `vulnerability` present inside each `results[]` which is under `data[]`

Current code approach is

```
severity_arr = raw['data'].each do |data|
  data['results'].each do |result|
    result['vulnerabilities'].map {|vulnerability| vulnerability['severity']}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flat_map` and `dig`:

```
data[:data].flat_map { |datum| datum.dig(:results, 0, :vulnerabilities) }
# [{:severity=>"high"}, {:severity=>"medium"}, {:severity=>"none"}, {:severity=>"high"}, {:severity=>"none"}, {:severity=>"none"}, {:severity=>"none"}, {:severity=>"high"}]
```

What's maybe not convenient, is that `data.results` holds an array with a single hash. Maybe a hash is enough for that.

Comment: `JSON.parse` (from `json` gem) will parse that will strings for keys instead of symbols. Should this be updated to use strings instead?

Comment: Sure, but that will clearly make this answer invalid for the example given in the question. You can always use `parse` with the `symbolize_names` option, or to adapt the dig arguments to use strings instead of symbols.

Comment: Not that it's worth fighting over, but I think you're mistaken. His example was properly formatted JSON, not Ruby code or data structures.

Comment: Don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: I get this error `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`. This is because `severity` is nested 3 levels deep. Data[] consists of results[] which consists of vulnerabilities[], vulnerabilities[] holds `severity` value.

Comment: I don't have that problem with the input you added to the question.

Comment: It's a valid formatted JSON. If I use your suggested logic
`data[:data].flat_map { |datum| datum.dig(:results, 0, :vulnerabilities) }` it throws the error. 

I thought it might be worth mentioning that I'm performing `JSON.parse('input.json')` before running a loop.

Comment: Yes, I'm not telling the opposite, don't worry. Can you add the exact output that `JSON.parse('input.json')` returns? It seems we're working with two different pieces of code.

Comment: Here's the exact output

`{"data"=>[{"file"=>"test/test_project_js/jquery.js", "results"=>[{"vulnerabilities"=>[{"severity"=>"high"}, {"severity"=>"medium"}, {"severity"=>"none"}, {"severity"=>"high"}]}]}, {"file"=>"test/test_project_js/jquery.js", "results"=>[{"vulnerabilities"=>[{"severity"=>"none"}, {"severity"=>"none"}, {"severity"=>"none"}, {"severity"=>"high"}]}]}]}`

Comment: Sure, that differs from the one in the question in that it has string keys, not symbol ones. Try `p ({"data"=>[{"file"=>"test/test_project_js/jquery.js","results"=>[{"vulnerabilities"=>[{"severity"=>"high"},{"severity"=>"medium"},{"severity"=>"none"},{"severity"=>"high"}]}]},{"file"=>"test/test_project_js/jquery.js","results"=>[{"vulnerabilities"=>[{"severity"=>"none"},{"severity"=>"none"},{"severity"=>"none"},{"severity"=>"high"}]}]}]}['data'].flat_map { |datum| datum.dig('results', 0, 'vulnerabilities') })`

Comment: This one works beautifully. My bad, I should've attached a valid JSON with `JSON.parse()` output. However, the output of this is an `array` and when I try to use `.include?` it always returns `false`. Say, I use severity_arr.include? 'high', it returns false even when `severity_arr` includes `high`.

Here's the output `[{"severity"=>"high"}, {"severity"=>"medium"}, {"severity"=>"none"}, {"severity"=>"high"}, {"severity"=>"none"}, {"severity"=>"none"}, {"severity"=>"none"}, {"severity"=>"high"}]`

Comment: That's becasue with `include?` the objects must match. You can try with `....include?({"severity" => "high"})` or `....any? { |severity| severity['severity'] == 'high' }`.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you for your time and suggestion!